# What is the retention time distribution in an STRcascade when the reactors are of uneven side and we have some recircultion?

Tags: chemical-engineering, process-engineering

Consider 2 or 3 stirred tank reactors as a cascade. The sizes are different. A part of the throughput is recirculated from the last to the first. The mean hydraulic retention of course is straightforward to calculate. But what is the [residence time distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residence_time_distribution)?

I think this is a solved problem, but for some reason the solution is not in any textbook I've consulted so far. Only the classical case of [stirred tank reactor (STR) (all same size, no recirculation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_stirred-tank_reactor).

What is the effect of recirculation on the RT distribution? Logic says the distribution will be closer to a single vessel, but how to quantify?

Is there a significant effect on the HRT distribution of a STR cascade when the tanks have different sizes?

As stated above, I'm sure this is a solved problem - I just haven't been able to find the solutions.